# Changing srcset in Firefox flickers image after transition

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two `<img>`-elements, where the first image should fade in, and the second image fade out. When the transition ends, I remove the class for fading in and out, and I switch the image sources of the tags.

```
<img id="in" class="in" [srcset]="inSrcSet" (transitionend)="transitionEndIn($event)">
<img id="out" class="out" [srcset]="outSrcSet" (transitionend)="transitionEndOut($event)">
```

in the component I am switching the srcset

```
// sample 
transitionEndIn(event){
   this.inSrcSet = "outSrcSet";
}
 transitionEndOut(event){
   this.outSrcSet = "inSrcSet";
}
```

This change in srcset is making the image flicker in Firefox. It looks like the image that is fading out is coming back to full opacity for a split second. However, I do not see any flickering if I am using regular `src` instead of `srcset`.

I have made a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjzma6) illustrating my problem. I have made an example with both src and srcset so you can see the difference. The problem does not occur in Chrome though. (I have not tested any other web browsers). The fade in/out is not a loop, so you have to refresh the Stackblitz in order to see the transition again.

Comment: Instead of programmatically swapping the srcset, why don't you just invert the two images by changing their z-index?

Comment: I am using this method as a custom carousel to fade in/out many images, where all the images will rotate. A new image will be placed in the `in`-element, transfered to the `out`-element, and then removed from DOM. In this example I only used two images for simplicity.